# tf2 listener: python working example (hydro)

Tags: ros, python, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a working example of the tf2 listener under hydro. I have tried to follow tutorials on the wiki but they seems to be outdated.

Just to check if I follow the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Migration/TransformListener) right. I have a simple example of `tf`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('cvut_sandbox')
import rospy
import tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("test_tf_listener")
    tfl = tf.TransformListener()
    (trans, rot) = tfl.waitForTransform('r1_link_1', 'r2_link_2', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(0))
```

This will fail under hydro due to bug reported [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/30) but works under groovy. Trying to follow the tutorial I ended up with version for `tf2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('cvut_sandbox')
import rospy
import tf2_ros

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("test_tf_listener")
    buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
    tfl = tf2_ros.TransformListener(buffer)
    (trans, rot) = tfl.waitForTransform('r1_link_1', 'r2_link_2', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(0))
```

However, it seems that it wont be so easy:

```
$ rosrun cvut_sandbox test_tf2_listener.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wagnelib/Source/hydro/clopema_ws/src/clopema_cvut/cvut_sandbox/scripts/test_tf2_listener.py", line 11, in <module>
    (trans, rot) = tfl.waitForTransform('r1_link_1', 'r2_link_2', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(0))
AttributeError: TransformListener instance has no attribute 'waitForTransform'
```

Following the [Writing a tf2 listener (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29) tutorial I ended with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('cvut_sandbox')
import rospy
import tf2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("test_tf_listener")
    tfl = tf2.TransformListener()
    (trans, rot) = tfl.waitForTransform('r1_link_1', 'r2_link_2', rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(0))
```

But it also fails:

```
$ rosrun cvut_sandbox test_tf2_listener_2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wagnelib/Source/hydro/clopema_ws/src/clopema_cvut/cvut_sandbox/scripts/test_tf2_listener.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tf2
ImportError: No module named tf2
```

So is there a working example?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76288/tf2-listener:-python-working-example-(hydro)/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/30 for the continuing discussion.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-19**:
And [that ticket](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/30) seems to be resolved. Marked as an answer.